# Are there other finite element types besides the usual?

Tags: finite-element-analysis, polyhedra

By finite element type I specifically mean element geometry. I am aware of Quad, Tri, Tet & Hex but are there other types, eg a hexagonal prism, rhombihedral etc..

Comment: This question seems better suited to https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: didnt realize that existed thankyou will ask there

Answer (score 0):

From a theoretical point of view, there is nothing that prevents creating such elements!

However, the complexity added but such odd types of geometry eliminates the benefits of using the finite element method in the first place.